# NullPointerException on fragment commit when running in Robolectric

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.WindowId.equals(WindowId.java:168)
    at android.transition.Transition.pause(Transition.java:1669)
    at android.transition.TransitionSet.pause(TransitionSet.java:483)
    at android.transition.TransitionManager.sceneChangeSetup(TransitionManager.java:311)
    at android.transition.TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(TransitionManager.java:415)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.beginDelayedTransition(FragmentTransitionCompat21.java:67)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.configureTransitions(BackStackRecord.java:1257)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.beginTransition(BackStackRecord.java:1077)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:678)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:130)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$100(ShadowMessageQueue.java:30)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:95)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:230)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:85)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.enqueueMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:116)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
    at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1557)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:654)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:621)
```

As you can see the exception is happening in `android.view.WindowId` class, so I doubt it's an error in my code. This is the code I'm running:

```
if (AndroidHelper.isLollipopAndAbove()) {
    Fade fadeIn = new Fade(Fade.IN);
    Fade fadeOut = new Fade(Fade.OUT);
    fadeIn.setDuration(200);
    fadeOut.setDuration(200);
    fragment.setEnterTransition(fadeIn);
    fragment.setExitTransition(fadeOut);
}
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, fragment);
if (keepInStack) {
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
}
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This works fine if I take out `fragment.setEnterTransition(fadeIn);` and `fragment.setExitTransition(fadeOut);`

Is there any way to work around this? No issue when running on a real device.

**EDIT**: just to be super clear, this is not an issue about a generic `NullPointerException` or my fragment being null or anything like that. This issue is something to do with running transition code inside Robolectric environment. To be even more specific, it's the `setExitTransition` that is causing this issue, and the issue seems to be only manifesting in `Robolectric`. `setEnterTransition` seems to be working just fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @xenteros Definitely not a duplicate of 'What is a NullPointer'. If you look closer the Null Pointer is happening inside `android.view.WindowId` class

Comment: Looks like your `fragment` is null! could you share your code where u are initialising fragment!

Comment: @Smit My fragment is not null. Please look at the stack in the question before posting comment like that as they are not helpful.

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience! But you u have mentioned that if you take out `fragment.setEnterTransition(fadeIn); and fragment.setExitTransition(fadeOut);` it works. So I assume that's the issue.

Comment: I'll update the question to make it more clear, thank. But the issue is with how the transitions are worked inside Robolectric I think, so I need a workaround.

Comment: @vkislicins
its too late but did you find the reason for this. I have the same issue but with setEnterTransition

Answer (score 0):

No matter what test framework are you actually use, `Robolectric`, `Espresso`, `Appium` - please. don't use animations for your test purposes.

I'm pretty sure that your problem is very similar to this: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1889 but in that case animations make `Robolectric` running endless.

Make a `MockFragment` class without transisions, intepolators, animators etc.

Comment: You're most likely right. Can you recommend any reading/article on how to create and manage mock fragments while excluding transitions, animations etc?